# ¿Como puedo evitar que php muestre su codigo de error y no el mio?

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Quiero que, cuando se produzca un error al conectar con la base de datos, se le muestre al usuario un mensaje creado por mi en vez de:

> No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión. in C:\xampp\Champion\htdocs\Practica3\model\Factoria.php on line 5
> Error al conectar.

```
function conectar()
{
```

`$bbdd = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicaph");`

```
if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo "Error al conectar";
    printf("Error conectando con la base de datos: %s\n", msqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}



return $bbdd;
}
```

Comment: PHP usa la arroba para [suprimir la salida de mensajes de error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Comment: Complementando las respuestas, no es buena idea dejar habilitada la muestra explícita de errores en producción, porque si hubiese otro error no controlado, va a dejar expuesta rutas, frameworks, incluso hasta versión de servidor. Usar entorno de "producción" en php.ini o `error_reporting(0);` en el servidor de la aplicación.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el bloque de código preparado para ello try/catch/finally [Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

```
try {
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} finally {
    echo "Segundo finally.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_connect()` devuelve `false` en caso de error. Entonces puedes evaluar el resultado de su llamada para mostrar un mensaje de error personalizado.

Sería tan simple como esto:

```
function conectar()
{
    $bbdd = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicaph");

    if(!$bbdd){
        echo "Error al conectar";
        exit();
    }
    return $bbdd;
}
```

Con ese código tu pregunta queda respondida.

### Una solución coherente y multifuncional

Pero hay un problema en el *estilo* de programación que intentas implementar y es la **coherencia**. En un código como ese, el programa terminaría simplemente con un mensaje de error. OK, pero hay un flujo y un contexto anterior que ha solicitado la conexión para trabajar con ella. ¿Qué pasa con ese flujo? No es justo salir o terminarlo con un simple mensaje. Además, en una aplicación considerable ese mismo código podría ser llamado desde miles de contextos. No deberías en ningún caso resolverlo con un mensaje y un `exit`, porque en cualquier contexto tu código podría quedar roto, sin respuesta.

La coherencia podría resolverse entonces en dos pasos:

1. Devolviendo `NULL` cuando no haya conexión.
2. En todos los contextos, verificar siempre el estado de la conexión antes de usarla.

Si aplicas esos criterios, podrías escribir el código así:

```
function conectar()
{
    $bbdd = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicaph");
    return $bbdd;
}
```

#### Dos ejemplos

1.- Un contexto cualquiera ... contexto 189, parecido al tuyo actual:

```
if ($mysqli=conectar()) {
    //usar $mysqli en ESTE contexto
} else {
    echo "Error en la conexión";
}
```

2.- Un contexto cualquiera ... contexto 99999 TOTALMENTE distinto al tuyo actual porque hay otros requerimientos. En este contexto tu función no se adaptaría ni sería flexible:

```
/*
    Hay un cambio en este contexto, 
    porque se trabajará con una variable $mData
    que deberá ser obtenida sí o sí, 
    en la base de datos, o en otra fuente alternativa
*/
$mData=array();    
if ($mysqli=conectar()) {
    //usar $mysqli en ESTE contexto para obtener $mData
} else {
    /*
       En este contexto, cuando no hay conexión
       se ha indicado pedir $mData en otro sitio
       por ejemplo, un servicio web, una API, Firebase, Amazon WS, etc.
       Por tanto no lo puedes resolver con un
       echo "Error en la conexión"; y saliendo
       Sino que aquí, en el else, debes lanzar la petición 
       a la fuente de datos alternativa
    */
    //Usar fuente alternativa para obtener $mData
}
/*
    Aquí trabajamos con $mData
    como podrás entender, si al intentar conectar devuelves
    un simple mensaje, no podrás evaluar con facilidad 
    que no hubo conexión y pasar a buscar los datos en otra parte
    no es que sea así en tu caso, es para explicar la importancia de la
    coherencia y del uso contextual
  */
```